# SubString not working in RSS feed Jquery

Tags: jquery, rss

On my following code, i am getting parameter date in this variable from Feedburner {shortBodyPlain}, now i need to substring this to get the date and the month, how do I achieve it? Moreover, How do I use the variable {date}, {title} in jquery?

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://sdepold.github.io/jquery-rss/src/jquery.rss.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        $("#events").rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/google/lkRN", {
            limit: 4,
            layoutTemplate: '<span id="entries">{entries}</span>',
            entryTemplate: '{date} <a href="{url}">{title}</a><br>'
        }).show();
    });
</script>
<div id="events"></div>
```

Comment: I am running a fiddle here at http://jsfiddle.net/AFHfn/101/

Comment: What do you mean you need date and month? Do you want to use them as different js variables somewhere on this page?

Comment: I need to fetch the date, month and status etc from these variable. Yes, i also need to use them as JS variables.

Comment: How about this http://jsfiddle.net/NrvNL/

Comment: @BharathRallapalli this is fine, but I need to store the values also so I can manipulate them. Using your approach, I am not able to display the date and the Month in the div.

Comment: @user2955432 You want to show the date and month in another div

Comment: @BharathRallapalli Yes, exactly. and then based upon the month i get in the variable, i need to show the events of the current month only.

Comment: May be you need like this http://jsfiddle.net/w6zAf/6/

Comment: @BharathRallapalli It is fine but I need to get the out put as dates correponding to the event names. This prints the events titles first and thn the dates.

Comment: I have changed it like this http://jsfiddle.net/a3LGN/8/

Comment: oops, Wrong fiddle :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try 'cheating' your way there by adding a token which does (almost) "nothing".

For example let's create a token `{alert-date}`.

```
$("#events-output").rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/google/lkRN", {
    limit: 4,
    tokens: {
        'alert-date': function (entry, tokens) {
            alert(tokens.date);
            return '';
        },
    },
    layoutTemplate: '<span id="entries">{entries}</span>',
    entryTemplate: '{date} <a href="{url}">{title}</a><br>{alert-date}'
}).show();
```

This way you create a function which generates the token contents each time a row is generated. You return empty string, so the token dissapears from the output contents, but the code from the function is actually ran. You can put the token anywhere in your template - it will be empty anyway always. Remember that instead of alerting the contents of `tokens.date` variable you can store them somewhere for later use.

Please run `console.log(tokens)` inside your token function - you can see all the tokens' contents and you don't need to parse html like someone else proposed.

Look at fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w6zAf/

---

**How to get more info from the date?**

You can generate date from your XML. It's easy in javascript as it does all the work for you. Instead of writing `alert(tokens.date)` in the code above you can generate new object date which is done this way:

```
var date = new Date(tokens.date);
var month = date.getMonth();
```

More here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

---

**Create token month and day**

```
$("#events-output").rss("http://feeds.feedburner.com/google/lkRN", {
    limit: 4,
    tokens: {
        'month': function (entry, tokens) {
            var date = new Date(tokens.date);
            return date.getMonth();
        },
        'day': function (entry, tokens) {
            var date = new Date(tokens.date);
            return date.getDay();
        },
    },
    layoutTemplate: '<span id="entries">{entries}</span>',
    entryTemplate: '{date} <a href="{url}">{title}</a><br>'
}).show();
```

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, but I have a question, what are tokens which are being used in your code? I have never heard of them. Also, I need to use the **substring** in the **variables** such as {date} in the code under _entryTemplate:_

Comment: I've explained this is just a 'cheat', that token {alert-date} is created by me. It's an option for you to create some customized tokens. If you want to create a token called month, then it's nothing hard - just look at my latest edit.

Comment: Btw, please read about templates and how to use them, cuz apparently you don't undestand that `{date}` and `{url}` etc, are not variables.

Comment: Btw, if the answer is correct for you then please also upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

you can receive value of {date}, {title} as follows in js:

```
var d = '{date}';
var t=  '{title}';
```